# How to setup blending for additive color overlays?

Tags: opengl

Is it possible in opengl to setup blending to achieve additive color overlays?

Red + green = yellow, cyan + magenta = white, etc.. (see [diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:AdditiveColor.svg))

Comment: uhm... I don't think cyan + magenta = white. R+G+B = white

Comment: G+B = C, and R+B = M, so C+M is equivalent to G+B+R+B. That's as white as you can get.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE);
```

should do it.

Have a look at the full description of [glBlendFunc](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glBlendFunc.xhtml)

EDIT: [Old tutorial link](http://www.processingblogs.org/2007/03/31/mini-tutorial-additive-blending/) seems to be dead (403 Forbidden).  [Wayback'd](http://web.archive.org/web/20081207015323/http://www.processingblogs.org/2007/03/31/mini-tutorial-additive-blending/).

Comment: First link gives error 403 and second link gives error 404. I guess it's not my day then...

Comment: Thanks, genpfault, for waybacking the tutorial link.

Answer (score 7):

Simple additive blending is achieved with glBlendFunc (GL_ONE, GL_ONE). You need to be aware of the fact that OpenGL's color value range is limited to [0,1], and values greater than 1 will be clamped to 1, so adding bright colors may not produce physically correctly blended colors. If you want to achieve that, you will have to add and scale the colors in your own software rather than having OpenGL handle it, or write a shader program that does that while rendering.